# How to know if a paramiko SSH channel is disconnected?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm desinging test cases in which I use paramiko for SSH connections. Test cases usually contain `paramiko.exec_command()` calls which I have a wrapper for (called `run_command()`). Here `self.ssh` is an intance of `paramiko.SSHClient()`. I use a decorator to check the ssh connection before each call. (`self.get_ssh()` negotiates the connection)

```python
def check_connections(function):
    ''' A decorator to check SSH connections. '''
    def deco(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.ssh is None:
            self.ssh = self.get_ssh()
        else:
            ret = getattr(self.ssh.get_transport(), 'is_active', None)
            if ret is None or (ret is not None and not ret()):
                self.ssh = self.get_ssh()
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return deco
```

```python
@check_connections
def run_command(self, command):
    ''' Executes command via SSH. '''
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(command)
    stdin.flush()
    stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
    ret = stdout.read()
    err = stderr.read()
    if ret:
        return ret
    elif err:
        return err
    else:
        return None
```

It works perfectly until my remote node reboots, which can happen sometimes. When it occurs the next `run_command()` call generates a `socket.error` exception. The problem is, that the `paramiko.Transport` object seems to be remain in active state until an exception is thrown:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar  7 2013, 14:03:36)
[GCC 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0x7f2397b96d50>
>>> print ssh.get_transport()
None
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.ssh/known_hosts')
>>> ssh.connect(hostname = '172.31.77.57', username = 'root', password = 'rootroot', timeout = 5.0)
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0x7f2397b96d50>
>>> print ssh.get_transport()
<paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>
>>> print ssh.get_transport().is_active()
True
>>> ssh.exec_command('ls')
(<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>, <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>, <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>)
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0x7f2397b96d50>
>>> print ssh.get_transport()
<paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>
>>> print ssh.get_transport().is_active()
True
>>> ssh.exec_command('reboot')
(<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>, <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>, <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>)
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0x7f2397b96d50>
>>> print ssh.get_transport()
<paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>
>>> print ssh.get_transport().is_active()
True
>>> ssh.exec_command('ls')
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pytest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 370, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session()
  File "/home/pytest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 662, in open_session
    return self.open_channel('session')
  File "/home/pytest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 764, in open_channel
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0x7f2397b96d50>
>>> print ssh.get_transport()
<paramiko.Transport at 0x97537550L (unconnected)>
>>> print ssh.get_transport().is_active()
False
>>>
```

**Question: how can I be sure that the connection is really active or not?**

Comment: Hey. The decorator you used, I do have a similar method to check if it's connected, and it will return True/False... The decorator makes the method altered by it just run if the decorator method returns True? Like, `just run if decorator return is True` ? The concept of decorators is kinda new to me.

Answer (score 12):

In python, it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Wrap each call to `ssh.exec_command` like so:

```
try:
    ssh.exec_command('ls')
except socket.error as e:
    # Crap, it's closed. Perhaps reopen and retry?
```

Comment: +1 however it's rather a workaround than a solution for me... I guess paramiko lacks what I need...

Comment: @milo - did you find a better solution to Paramiko? I'm in the exact same position as you.

Comment: No, but I haven't done any research on it recently. I think it has to be done this way. (Sorry for the late reply.)

Comment: Hey, what if  I'm in between a command that takes 5 minutes to finish and I lost connection to the server. How do I check whether connection is active or not ?

Comment: @VooDooNOFX SO banned me! I can't ask new question. Thanks!

Comment: A heads up on this, `socket.error` is an alias for `OSError` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.error), meaning for instance that you can accidentally catch `FileNotFoundError` which can be raised by the `paramiko.SFTPClient`.

Comment: @Milo I agree with you on this. I mean, we have the get_transport() method on "Client" to see if a Transport is active, but we don't have a get_channel() on Transport... It does not make sense for me. It would be so much easier, since in Channel itself we have get_id() of channel... It would facilitate our life a lot, and even make handling multiple connections on the same session much easier.

Answer (score 5):

My solution basically the same as yours, just organized differently:

```
def connection(self):
    if not self.is_connected():
        self._ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self._ssh.connect(self.server, self.port,
                          username = self.username, password = self.password)

    return self._ssh

def is_connected(self):
    transport = self._ssh.get_transport() if self._ssh else None
    return transport and transport.is_active()

def do_something(self):
    self.connection().exec_command('ls')
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())        # Setting the missing host policy to auto add it
client.connect('192.168.1.16', port=22, username='admin', password='admin', timeout=3, banner_timeout=2)

channel = client.invoke_shell()                 # Request an interactive shell session on this channel. If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly connected to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the shell.
print channel.closed          # False
command = 'reboot'
channel.send(command + '\n')
# wait a while
print channel.closed          # True
```

Answer (score 3):

I´ll just throw this here since someone might find it usefull. There is one catch with some of these methods. `Paramiko` internally uses `sockets`. Every new connection calls `socket` which opens a new file descriptor. Since processes are limited to certain number of open file descriptors after some time you will run out which will result in:

`socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files`.

So it is better to explicitly try to close the connection before establishing a new one using `SSHClient.close()` method.