# paramiko hangs on unexpected connection drops

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm using `paramiko` for SSH connection with server. `exec_command` always hangs forever if server becomes unavailable (for example unexpectedly turned off) and timeout doesn't actually work.
I also tried `set_keepalive`, but it doesn't work either. As far as I understood from source codes keepalive is implemented for server. It just sends something to the server periodically to keep connection alive, but doesn't check for any read timeout on the client side.

Is there any way to handle unexpected connection drops? Maybe you can suggest something better then `paramiko` or the way I can fix it?

I also tried to set TCP level keep alive, but it doesn't help much.

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 10)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the timeout to work, you probably need to use

```
import socket
socket.settimeout(<timeoutinseconds>)
```

This should set the timeout so that paramiko will respect it. Then if the timeout is reached it should throw an exception you can handle

Comment: connect method takes timeout and calls sock.settimeout(timeout). This function is called and timeout is set, however this doesn't help in case of unexpected power off. If you turn of (not shut down) your SSH server client will hang forever.

Comment: For linux ssh client you can use `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=5` and it works perfectly fine, but I can't find such an option for paramiko.

Comment: Are you using ssh with key auth? Do you really need to hold the connections open for a long time while they might be idle?

Comment: I'd probably just re-connect each time or run a small test on the connection before the main command and catching exceptions. This thread looks to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147902/how-to-know-if-a-paramiko-ssh-channel-is-disconnected

Comment: The problem is that it never throws an exception. It hangs and `exec_command` never returns.